# How Can I Underline the Button Text of UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

The text is coming form a database. I would like to use it for a button and underline the text of the button. How can I do that?

Comment: Here is how to do same in storyboard (XCode 6).

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26930512/309046

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can subclass `UILabel` and overwrite its `-drawRect` method and then use your own `UILabel` and add a `UIButton` over it of custom type.

Make your drawRect method in UILabel as

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 207.0f/255.0f, 91.0f/255.0f, 44.0f/255.0f, 1.0f);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height - 1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - 1);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    [super drawRect:rect]; 

}
```

Answer (score 44):

In iOS 6, **NSAttributedString** is used modifying the text, you can use "NSMutableAttributedString" for multi color text, font, style, etc using single UIButton or UILabel.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *titleString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"The Underlined text"];

// making text property to underline text-
[titleString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [titleString length])];

// using text on button
[button setAttributedTitle: titleString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: can we make the line lower ?

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3 the following extension can be used for an underline:

```
extension UIButton {
    func underlineButton(text: String) {
        let titleString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        titleString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count))
        self.setAttributedTitle(titleString, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this a bit simpler (it's a common requirement) I've built a simple UIButton subclass called BVUnderlineButton that you can drop straight into your projects.

It's on Github at https://github.com/benvium/BVUnderlineButton (MIT licence).

You can use it in a XIB / Storyboard or direct via code.