# UIButton title blinking when iam using undreline with button title

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am using below code for button title with underline

```
 NSDictionary *underlineAttribute = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)};
[btn setAttributedTitle:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"See Event TnC" attributes:underlineAttribute] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Are you getting this is simulator or device?

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/17585294/5362916

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello vikramarkaios you can change the UIButton type system to Custom in button of attributes

[image]

i hope it's helps for you!!

Comment: Thank u for your helping. Now.. i am not getting blinking of the button title

Answer (score 0):

You can disable animation on UIView before setting the button title.

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
NSDictionary *underlineAttribute = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)};
[btn setAttributedTitle:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"See Event TnC" attributes:underlineAttribute] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: I think you forgot something. It was supposed to be like this.NSDictionary *underlineAttribute = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)};  NSMutableAttributedString *attributedStr= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"ABC"];
    [attributedStr setAttributes:underlineAttribute range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedStr.length)];
    [obj setAttributedTitle:attributedStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

From iOS6 it is now possible to use an NSAttributedString to perform underlining (and anything else attributed strings support) in a much more flexible way:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *commentString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"The Quick Brown Fox"];

[commentString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [commentString length])];
```

Note: added this as another answer - as its a totally different solution to my previous one.

oddly (in iOS8 at least) you have to underline the first character otherwise it doesn't work!

so as a workaround, set the first char underlined with clear colour!

```
NSMutableAttributedString* tncString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"View Terms and Conditions"];

    // workaround for bug in UIButton - first char needs to be underlined for some reason!
    [tncString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                      value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)
                      range:(NSRange){0,1}];
    [tncString addAttribute:NSUnderlineColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];


    [tncString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                      value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)
                      range:(NSRange){5,[tncString length] - 5}];

    [tncBtn setAttributedTitle:tncString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```