# Hyperlinks in iPhone/iPad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, view, hyperlink

I want to give hyperlink on my iPhone/iPad view.I want to click on some text and open new view.I have tried to give hyperlink on my UILable .But it dint work...How should I do this?

Comment: I have extended or subclassed UILabel and I have made a custom control for the label. If you need that label then please let me know

Comment: @Khushbu Shah : You can get this answer only by search on SO or google. Just try to search something by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use a UIButton, and have it link out as (others have said). You can set the button's type to be UIButtonTypeCustom.

If you want your text to be underlined like a real hyperlink, I find the best solution is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841248/951830) one.

Comment: Thanks to all...uptill now I was using UIButton for sthis..
And it is working perfect....
But I just wanted to know that is there possible to have hyperlinks on UILable ? Is it possible or not.

Comment: @KhushbuShah: Yes it is possible by subclassing UILabel and I have made a custom control for the same. Please let me know if you need it.

Comment: @ParthBhatt - Right now I don't have need for this..This time I have used UIButton for hyperlink.But just for a sake of knowledge I was asking..

Comment: @KhushbuShah: Ok fine. Do let me know in case if you need it.

Comment: @ParthBhatt - If you don't have problem than can You give me just for knowing?

Comment: @KhushbuShah: Yes sure. But where should I send it? Whats your Email ID?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7727/discussion-between-parth-bhatt-and-khushbu-shah)

Comment: @KhushbuShah: Ok now you can delete your email ID for the privacy purpose.

Comment: @KhushbuShah: Did you get the intime and outtime issue solved?

Comment: @ParthBhatt- you told me about PHP project..Can you give me information...?

Answer (score 1):

Set a `UIButton` with button type set to `Custom` and set its title to the website address, in its action you can give the code to open the url.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your Touches Begin or end method....

```
    -(void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
        {
           UITouch* touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

           CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

           CGRect firstLinkRect = CGRectMake(36, 11, 150, 12);  // your UILabel Rect

            // NSLog(@"X: @%f \n Y: @%f",location.x, location.y);

           if (CGRectContainsPoint(firstLinkRect, location)) 
             {
              //NSLog(@"Get First point");
                NSURL *target = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
               [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:target];
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use uibutton for that and put image which look like link.

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this text must be a part of textView or label? you may add UIButton with custon type and your linktext/image/or something

Answer (score 0):

This if you want to put the hyperlink into iphone development for the we use the UIButton in which the we gives the IBAction method to give him

And best example give here so u can get the idea about it.

[Refrence link here.](http://sugartin.info/2012/02/03/show-map-show-website-send-mail-make-a-phone-call-all-in-one-sample-code/)

Happy coding

Thanks ,

@samuel