# How to add underline below text of UIButton in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Underlining text in UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630004/underlining-text-in-uibutton)

i have added custom button in UITableViewCell, i want to give title with underlined text.
How we can achieve this by code or interface builder?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel/2711587#2711587

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630004/underlining-text-in-uibutton