# UIButton setAttributedTitle: forState: Not Showing Up

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uibutton, nsattributedstring

I am trying to add underlining to my title on a custom UIButton but by following the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930032/329900), I can't get it to show on the screen.

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *commentString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"The Quick Brown Fox"];

[commentString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [commentString length])];

[button setAttributedTitle:commentString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This doesn't show up. But if I just do a regular one, like so:

```
[button setTitle:@"The Quick Brown Fox" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This shows up fine. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: My answer was incorrect, so I deleted it. What version of iOS are you targeting?

Comment: @Firo iOS 6.0 or later

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I realized the problem here. I assumed that it was not showing up because I could not see it. However, it was showing up, it is just the same color as the background.

I wrongly assumed that `[button setTitleColor:myColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];` would be the color that the attributedTitle would use as well. However, my background is black and the NSMutableAttributedString must default to black.

```
[commentString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:myColor  range:NSMakeRange(0, [commentString length])];
```

Makes it show up correctly.

Comment: FYI, @middaparka's reply above doesn't relate to my answer. It was in reply to a disgruntled user who wanted to know why their incorrect answer had been down voted.